# Show hidden button on droppable :: javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Even if only one icon from my draggable box is dropped into the droppable area, I would like a hidden button to appear.

I am unsure if I could reference the css class I used to hide it or have the JavaScript generate the button.

**This button will be needed later for an `onClick` event for a modal box.**

Any help would be appreciated. :)

jsfiddle to look at http://jsfiddle.net/JeLZr/4/

The code below is what I am having issues with.

```
if ($(this).find('.draggable').length === 0) {
    $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
    if($(ui.draggable).find('button.generateReport').length === 0){
        $(ui.draggable).append('<input type="button" id="generateReport" class="BtnReport"  />');
    }
}
```

[edit] I realize this is a lot of to ask but is there any chance anyone can help with; as well as dragging the icon, if it is double clicked it will move into the droppable box?? Is this even possible with draggable/droppable??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An attempt to answer the first question:

```
 $("#drop").droppable({
        accept: ".draggable",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $('.BtnReport').show();
            console.log("drop");
            $(this).addClass("over");
            var dropped = ui.draggable;
            var droppedOn = $(this);
            $(dropped).detach().css({
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            }).appendTo(droppedOn);


        },
        over: function (event, elem) {
            $(this).addClass("over");
            console.log("over");
        },
        out: function (event, elem) {
            $(this).removeClass("over");
        }
    });
    $("#drop").sortable();

    $("#grid").droppable({
        accept: ".draggable",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            if($('#drop img').length == 1)
                $('.BtnReport').hide();                
            console.log("drop");
            $(this).removeClass("over");
            var dropped = ui.draggable;
            var droppedOn = $(this);
            $(dropped).detach().css({
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            }).appendTo(droppedOn);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/JeLZr/5/

I can look into the second question as well but it might be best to Create another question for it.

Comment: With $(".draggable").draggable({revert: "invalid" }); added at the top of this code it worked wonderfully, thank you very much. I didn't think about calling the image directly.. I was making it harder for myself by calling the actual div. 
Thanks for the help Trevor. :) 
I will make another question for the double click, I will attempt something myself first, of course. cheers again. :D